# Using Leaflet Search plugin with GeoJSON layer (L.Control.Search)

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping

I have a map with a single GeoJSON layer that I referenced in my script (using the AJAX plugin). Now I am trying to add search functionality to the map so that the user can search for features by name. The plugin I am using is the [Leaflet Search plugin](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search).

However, I cannot get the search to perform, as it's giving me the "Location not found" error, whenever I type text into the search box. Here is my code:

```
searchlayer = L.geoJSON.ajax('data.json').addTo(map); 
map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({layer:searchlayer});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I assume that I'm not properly linking the layer and the field to be searched to the search control, but how do I do that?

**Found that the issue was not adding the option for the control to search the geojson attribute. The default column that the search button works on is "title". I added the option of propertyName: 'Location' to L.Control.Search and it works perfect now!**

Answer (score 4):

Might be problem with GeoJSON data not being available yet when layer is added to control. Try with this:

```
searchlayer = L.geoJSON.ajax('data.json').addTo(map);
searchlayer.on('data:loaded', function() {
  map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({layer:searchlayer});
});
```

Comment: This would probably be a better way to write my code. But turns out the issue was not adding the option of propertyName. It was searching the geoJSON for a column named "title" according to default rules. I simply changed it to the attrobute I wanted and it works.

Comment: Good! I see you also edited your question and added the solution to your problem. It's nice in such a case to mark somehow the added/changed part, for example: EDIT (in bold).